# Separate Interface or Utility class for defining constants in core java project

Tags: java

I am working on a project (using JDK7) which has 30 to 40 constants. These constants are being used by many classes of my project. I want to separate these constants into a single file. Which type of file should I prefer?, Interface or Utility class, I am thinking of using interface. Would it be appropriate ?

Comment: No. This would be the [Constant `interface` antipattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_interface). Do not abuse inheritance to save on a few lines of code. Either use an `enum` or a `properties` file. Preferably the file.

Comment: I'd go with an externalized `*.properties` file and a resource class that reads it and exposes to other classes. Not very often these constants are really constant and then it's better to have them in a properties file that can be edited without recompiling the project itself. For the ones that are really constants use `enum`s

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer. But if you have "Constants" which may change and all your code will work if you only change the value, then a property file whould indeed be the best solution.

Comment: @Rainer In my projects constants aren't going to change that's why I am not thinking of using property file. I was confused between a class with private constructor and Interface. But now after reading all the comments and answers. I am sure that I should avoid Constant Interface. So I'll stick with enum or a class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the SonarQube rules [Constants should not be defined in interfaces](https://sbforge.org/sonar/rules/show/squid:S1214?layout=false)

[image: Example from Eclipse with sonar binding]

You should use a class or an enum.

Answer (score 2):

I use a class with a private constructor in the case.

But be aware you should only put constants together in one file it there is a conceptual connection between them. Do not simply store a bunch of unrelated constants in a class.

If the constants may change over time because they are more of the configuration type, I would go the extra effort to store them in a configuration file.

Answer (score 1):

I do it like this..

```
class Constants {

private Constants() {

}

public static final String CONST_1 = "";
//add your constants here as public static final properties

}
```